# Instagram search bar with selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am working on a program that can type something in the instagram search bar. Here is the code of the website:

```
<input class="XTCLo x3qfX " placeholder="Rechercher" value="" type="text">
```

I have already seen some posts about that but they did not work with me. Here is my code:

```
input_search = wait(browser, 10).until(
EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Rechercher']")
))
action=ActionChains(browser)
action.move_to_element(input_search)
action.send_keys(search)
action.click()
action.perform()
```

how can I correct that ?

Comment: Please elaborate `did not work`? Error?? Stack trace???

Comment: Here is the error :selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: _TimeoutException_ is the outcome of **failed** _expected-conditions_. Debug your code through `find_element_by_*` inconjunction with `time.sleep()`. If you are able to locate the element, update the question with the observations.

Comment: Can you update the question with the relevant _HTML_?

Comment: Done could you help me to solve the problem please ?

Comment: Well, observe the `<input>` tag closely, _AUT_ is _React_ based so `class` attribute won't help us. `placeholder` attribute should have worked. But the _Instagram_ server accessed from _India_ possibly renders a different DOM (as I observed on Chrome). So a bit more of the _outerHTML_ may help us to construct an answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't search by placeholder text as it will change with the browser language. You should use the locator which will be consistent across all the browser languages.

In your scenario if the browser language is English then placeholder text will be "Search".

I have modified your code.

Code Snippet:

```
input_search = wait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@class,'XTCLo')]")))
input_search.click()
input_search.send_keys("search")
```

Comment: It's still did not work.. I try other and they don't work either. Do you have other idea ?

Comment: ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused